# Raspberry Pi processing power

Tags: gpu, opengles

I've never worked with Raspberry Pi's, but I want to make some cute interactive shaders to put around the house and I was wondering if I could use a Raspberry Pi. I just wanted to know what one is comparable to in terms of rendering/simulation power.

Would I be able to do volumetric clouds and liquids? Both rendering and simulation, while also processing input? Should I use an alternative board with a GPU?

I've always worked with large PC's so this all-in-one space is very new to me and any information would be very helpful.

Comment: Raspberry Pi is frequently benchmarked against itself and other processors. Graphics processing is not its core strength. It can do rudimentary image recognition, etc. Search for particular benchmarks of interest. Given your requirements, I'd be pessimistic.